Dificultad para mostrar el status de una transacción debido problemas de precisión de números de punto flortante
En la empresa donde trabajo estamos tratando de implementar un sistema simple para poder llevar el record de $5 que se distribuyen por empleado durante el mes. Por lo tanto, he creado un formulario con Google Forms que al llenarse y mandarse se activa un script que actualiza el saldo (incialmente en $5.00) y descuenta la cantidad utilizada. Finalmente, manda un correo a gmail con el resumen de la transaccion y tambien despliega una app web a través de un link con el resumen de la transacción. EL problema que experimento es que cuando quiero gastar $4.99 de un solo, sí me realiza la operación pero el estatus me lo deja en 'transacción fallida'. A veces pasa lo mismo cuando ya solo tengo $4.00 y quiero retirar $3.55, me tira un montón de decimales y de paso me la coloca en 'fallida'. He investigado que es porque los flotantes no siempre funcionan bien cuando se pasan a binarios. Por lo que decidí cambiar de estrategia, agregar una columna más con que me registre si la transacción es válida o inválida de acuerdo a si la columna del saldo se ve disminuida o no.
He utilizado métodos como Number.EPSILON y .toFixed(2) sin éxito alguno. ¿qué es lo que ocurre en realidad y como lo puedo solucionar?
function getLatestMessage() {
  var responsesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("respuestas_formulario");
  var employeesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Empleados");
  var lastRow = responsesSheet.getLastRow();

  // Obtener los valores de la última fila de respuestas_formulario
  var lastResponse = responsesSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 5).getValues()[0];
  var lastEmployeeID = lastResponse[1];
  var pin = lastResponse[2];
  var amount = parseFloat(lastResponse[3]);
  var status_transaccion = lastResponse[4];

  // Buscar el empleado en la hoja 'Empleados' usando el ID
  var employeesData = employeesSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var nombre = "Desconocido";
  var saldo = "Desconocido";
  var empleadoEncontrado = false;

  for (var i = 1; i < employeesData.length; i++) {
    if (employeesData[i][0].toString() === lastEmployeeID.toString() && employeesData[i][3] === pin) {
      nombre = employeesData[i][1]; // Nombre del empleado
      saldo = parseFloat(employeesData[i][4]); // Saldo del empleado
      empleadoEncontrado = true;
      if (saldo >= amount) {
        status_transaccion = "válida";
        saldo = saldo - amount;
        employeesSheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue(saldo); // Actualiza el saldo en la hoja Empleados
      } else if (saldo < amount) {
        status_transaccion = "fallida";
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!empleadoEncontrado) {
    var message = "<div class='fallida'>Usuario o PIN incorrectos. Inténtelo nuevamente.</div>";
    return message;
  }

  // Redondear saldo
  saldo = Math.round((saldo + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;

  // Actualizar el estado de la transacción en respuestas_formulario
  responsesSheet.getRange(lastRow, 5).setValue(status_transaccion); // Actualiza el estado de la transacción en la hoja respuestas_formulario

  // Crear el mensaje usando la lógica proporcionada
  var transaccionMensaje = status_transaccion === "válida" ? "<div class='valida'>Transacción: válida</div>" : "<div class='fallida'>Transacción: fallida</div>";
  var saldoMensaje = "<div>Saldo: <span class='saldo'>$" + saldo.toFixed(2) + "</span></div>";

  var message = "<div>Nombre: " + nombre + "</div>" +
                "<div>Código de Empleado: " + lastEmployeeID + "</div>" +
                "<div>PIN del día: " + pin + "</div>" +
                transaccionMensaje +
                saldoMensaje;

  return message;
}


Debes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [MCVE], porque tal como está tu código no se aprecia que exista algún problema, ya que según entiendo tu if es  if (5 >= 4.99) que siempre es verdadero y el else if (5< 4.99) es siempre falso, por lo que no veo motivos para que te quede status_transaccion = "fallida";

Primero algunas notas sobre tu código y descripción del problema:

Precisión de float: Si bien es cierto que los números de coma flotante tienen problemas de precisión, no es algo que regularmente te afecte en una única suma o resta con números pequeños y con 2 decimales, pues la precisión es mucho mayor y, digamos que tienes 4.99 y quieres gastar 4.98, y que estos no se pueden representar en binario y que el mayor falla hacia abajo y el menor falla hacia arriba, pero 4.9899999999 siempre va a ser mayor que 4.9800000001, por lo que tus comparaciones debieran funcionar.
Javascript utiliza números de double precisión (IEEE754), que fácilmente pueden manejar sumas de cientos millones de dólares sin mayor dificultad. Si que estos errores de precisión se pueden acumular hasta verse reflejadas en los dígitos significativos, pero con sumas y restas, eso ocurre cuando haces cientos de miles de ellas sobre una misma variable.

El uso de .toFixed() para hacer los cálculos no podría ser la solución, porque te devuelve una cadena de caracteres que tiene solo N decimales, pero al hacer la conversión de vuelta para usarla como número, vuelves a los números de coma flotante, dónde probablemente un número no se pueda representar. Como he dicho en el punto anterior, ese no es el problema, pero tampoco esta sería la solución si lo fuera.

Para asegurarte de no tener problemas de precisión o de redondeo, puedes trabajar con enteros. Dado que tu moneda siempre tiene 2 decimales, multiplica todos los números por 100 y redondéalos antes de hacer los cálculos. Javascript los va a almacenar siempre como números de coma flotante, pues no tiene enteros, pero a menos que fueran números muy grandes, XXX.00 generalmente va a tener una representación binaria exacta.
Al final, para almacenar o mostrar mensajes, los divides de nuevo entre 100.

Por todo lo dicho antes, no le sumes Number.EPSILON al saldo, ni a nada, no hace falta, y solo aumentas la imprecisión. Number.EPSILON se utiliza para comparar igualdad de números, mediante la comparación del resultado de la  suma o resta de ellos.  Por ejemplo, si tú esperas que A sea igual a B, pero ambos son producto de operaciones aritméticas anteriores, corres el riesgo que la comparación A == B devuelva falso por problemas de precisión, entonces comparas Math.abs(A - B) <= Number.EPSILON. Eso siempre te va a devolver true si los números son iguales.

Si en el if (saldo >= amount) la condición no se cumple y se va al else, no hace falta el segundo if, esa condición ya se cumple (o es la primera o es la segunda). Hacerla es un desperdicio de ciclos de reloj.

Es probable que estés enfrentándote al problema que el usuario ingrese más dígitos de los 2 que son aceptables, o que los datos almacenados ya tengan imprecisiones más allá de los 2 dígitos. Por eso, es importante que apliques un redondeo al tomar los datos de las hojas y almacenarlos en tus variables y que trabajes sobre esos números que ya cuentan con la precisión correcta.


He preparado una versión de tu script siguiendo mis recomendaciones anteriores.
Además, para ayudarte a entender lo que pasa, he agregado un mensaje de depuración que, una vez todo funcione bien, debieras eliminar en la versión de producción. En este mensaje se muestra los números de entrada con 6 decimales, para que seas consciente de lo que está en las hojas, y luego con 2, que es lo que tu programa procesa.
En caso de que el saldo no resulte suficiente, se imprimen los valores del monto y del saldo en el mensaje de debug. Si te sigue dando dificultad con gastar 4.99 vs un saldo de 5.00, sería interesante ver que salió en ese mensaje para entender qué otro origen puede tener el problema.
Para evitar confusiones, he cambiado los nombres de las variables del monto y del saldo a intXXX, de manera que quede claro que tienen un número entero, que es el valor real multiplicado por 100.
El script resultante es este:
function getLatestMessage() {
  var debugMsg = "";
  var responsesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("respuestas_formulario");
  var employeesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Empleados");
  var lastRow = responsesSheet.getLastRow();

  // Obtener los valores de la última fila de respuestas_formulario
  var lastResponse = responsesSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 5).getValues()[0];
  var lastEmployeeID = lastResponse[1];
  var pin = lastResponse[2];
  var intamount = Math.round(parseFloat(lastResponse[3]) * 100);
  var status_transaccion = lastResponse[4];
  debugMsg += "Monto real: " + parseFloat(lastResponse[3]).toFixed(6) + "<br>";
  debugMsg += "Monto procesado: " + (intamount/100).toFixed(2) + "<br>";

  // Buscar el empleado en la hoja 'Empleados' usando el ID
  var employeesData = employeesSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var nombre = "Desconocido";
  var intsaldo = "Desconocido";
  var empleadoEncontrado = false;

  for (var i = 1; i < employeesData.length; i++) {
    if (employeesData[i][0].toString() === lastEmployeeID.toString() && employeesData[i][3] === pin) {
      nombre = employeesData[i][1]; // Nombre del empleado
      intsaldo = Math.round(parseFloat(employeesData[i][4]) * 100); // Saldo del empleado
      empleadoEncontrado = true;
      debugMsg += "Saldo original real: " + parseFloat(employeesData[i][4]).toFixed(6) + "<br>";
      debugMsg += "Saldo original procesado: " + (intsaldo/100).toFixed(2) + "<br>";
      if (intsaldo >= intamount) {
        status_transaccion = "válida";
        intsaldo = Math.round(intsaldo - intamount);
        debugMsg += "Nuevo saldo: " + (intsaldo/100).toFixed(2) + "<br>";
        employeesSheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue(intsaldo/100); // Actualiza el saldo en la hoja Empleados
      } else {
        status_transaccion = "fallida";
        debugMsg += "Saldo insuficiente: " intsaldo + "<" + intamount + "<br>";
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!empleadoEncontrado) {
    var message = "<div class='fallida'>Usuario o PIN incorrectos. Inténtelo nuevamente.</div>";
    return message;
  }

  // Actualizar el estado de la transacción en respuestas_formulario
  responsesSheet.getRange(lastRow, 5).setValue(status_transaccion); 

  // Crear el mensaje usando la lógica proporcionada
  var transaccionMensaje = status_transaccion === "válida" ? "<div class='valida'>Transacción: válida</div>" : "<div class='fallida'>Transacción: fallida</div>";
  var saldoMensaje = "<div>Saldo: <span class='saldo'>$" + (intsaldo/100).toFixed(2) + "</span></div>";

  var divDebug = "<div>Debug:<br>" + debugMsg + "</div>";

  var message = "<div>Nombre: " + nombre + "</div>" +
                "<div>Código de Empleado: " + lastEmployeeID + "</div>" +
                "<div>PIN del día: " + pin + "</div>" +
                transaccionMensaje +
                saldoMensaje +
                divDebug;

  return message;
}

OJO: He realizado los cambios del script directamente en la respuesta, no tengo manera de probarlo, pero si tiene errores, debieran resultar no tan complicados de corregir. Si encuentras alguna dificultad o tienes dudas, no dudes en dejar un comentario.
